# Recibir distintos valores de una variable PHP en text de HTML

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Quiero almacenar esto:

include 'reporte.php';
    require 'conexion.php';

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mvs";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes? Es decir, ¿qué problema tienes a la hora de introducir el valor en HTML? ¿Quieres que tenga el valor dentro de la etiqueta `<input type="text">`? ¿A qué te refieres con "distintos valores de una variable"?

Comment: exactamnte a eso quiero que tenga el valor dentro de la etiqueta <input type="text">

Comment: Espero que mi respuesta sea lo que buscabas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para introducir el valor de una variable PHP dentro de una etiqueta `<input>` necesitas agregarlo dentro del atributo `value` escapando los caracteres con `htmlspecialchars`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="calAld" id="calAld"
  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row3->calificacion) ?>" placeholder="" readonly />
```

Además, creo que lo que quieres hacer es asignar a una variable el contenido de la fila, y en su lugar intentas acceder a la propiedad `row` de una variable que parece que no tienes definida:

```
<?php foreach($query3 as $row3) {
    $calificacionaldrete0 = $row3->totalm0;
    $calificacionaldrete15 = $row3->totalm15;
    $calificacionaldrete30 = $row3->totalm30;
    $calificacionaldrete45 = $row3->totalm45;
    $calificacionaldrete60 = $row3->totalm60;
    $calificacionaldrete90 = $row3->totalm90;
    ?>
```

Comment: el problema es que me muestra que las variables asignadas arriba no estan declaradas :( soy nueva programando y no se como hacerlo

Comment: Vayamos por partes. ¿Qué variables? ¿Podrías compartir el/los mensajes de error/advertencia de los que hablas? Edita tu pregunta y agrégalos al final.

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: calificacionaldrete0

Filename: Recuperacion/altaRecup.php

Line Number: 42

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\bioanestesys\application\views\Panel\Pos\Recuperacion\altaRecup.php
Line: 42
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\bioanestesys\application\controllers\Pos\Recuperacion\CtrlAltaRecup.php
Line: 22
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\bioanestesys\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Todo lo que aparece al principio de mi pregunta se supone que son variables

Comment: Mira mi nueva edición

Comment: to get property of non-object

Filename: Recuperacion/altaRecup.php

Comment: Por favor, escríbelo en tu pregunta y también dime a qué línea corresponde el error. Parece que en algún lado accedes a un método de una variable que no es un objeto.

Comment: si era que no me fije y en una deje  esto -> ahora solo me falta mostrar un promedio en el <input type="text">

Comment: Si mi respuesta solucionó tu duda agradecería que la marcaras como correcta. Si tienes una nueva duda (por ejemplo, cómo calcular un promedio y mostrarlo) te recomendaría que abrieras una nueva pregunta para no mezclar temas. Gracias.

Comment: claro y gracias por la sugerencia si abrire el tema ... de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, fue un placer ayudar.